# regarding controlling the setup of index column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a data frame, `data_plot` looks like the following,

[image]

After operating the `data_plot` as follows

```
data_plot['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_plot['Time'])
df = data_plot.resample('M', on='Time').sum()
```

I got `df` as follows, the `Time column` has become into index column.

[image]

I have to use df.reset_index(inplace=true) to ensure 'Time' column not index column. If I want to avoid the last step of `reset_index`, how to modify the step of `df = data_plot.resample('M', on='Time').sum()`

[image]

Comment: Do you need `df = data_plot.resample('M', on='Time').sum().reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for your quick response, that is what I need. I will just close my post. Thanks.